# Realm import db from csv. How to define primary

Tags: android, database, realm, primary-key, realm-database

Im trying to create realm db from csv file but realm studio fail while creating with this error :

> Attempting to create an object of type  with an exixting
>   primary key value 'null'.

How to define primary key in csv file ? Or what is my mistake?

[image: CSV FILE]

Comment: @smoothBlue im not sure how pojo class can help here. Realm studio creates it by itself. But anyway, i found a solution, looks like smth with file was wrong, i just copied a data to example file from realm docs, and it works.Thanks for trying to help.